# Set CreatedOn property as current date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am following the below link to try and solve my issue..

[StackOverflow Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039876/assign-current-date-to-a-property-in-mvc)

The issue i have is i cant populate a field in my web form with the current date.

Im using SQL 2014 and have the a column field named 'CreatedOn', this is set as a datetime datatype.

I have a model which hold this the properties for this web form as per the code below:

```
namespace EDTSystem.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class Marie_Testing
    {
        //public int id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Client Ref:")]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Created By:")]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public class MyClass
        {
            private DateTime _CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            public DateTime CreatedOn { get { return _CreatedOn; } set { _CreatedOn = value; } }
        }
    }
}
```

I also have the below code for my Create.cshtml page that holds razor syntax:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="CreatedOn"> CreatedOn:</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyClass, new {@class = "form-control", style = "width:185px;background:E1EBF9;", @readonly = "readonly" })
</div>
```

All i intend to do is populate this Created on web field with the current date and time.

I tried to set this in the code view of the controller page by using CreatedOn - Datetime.Now but this doesn't and many posts have explained this gets set after the record has been submitted to the database and wont display in the web page as a default time and date.

Another method i used was setting this as a default in SQL but once again this is completed after the page has been submitted.

Comment: Your model makes no sense (having a nested class that contains a property for the date) and you should replace `public class MyClass { ... }` with a simple property `public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }`. But do not include a form control for it in the view. That value needs to be set immediately before you save the object to the database in the POST method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let's speak about couple of things:

First of all, you don't need that field here, as it's not doing anything, I would suggest to use auto Property here. You can set current `DateTime` in `constructor`.

```
 public class Marie_Testing
        {
            public Marie_Testing() {
                 CreatedOn  = DateTime.Now;
            }
            public DateTime CreatedOn { get;set; }

            //rest of your code

        }
```

Then on the View you want specify exact property:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="CreatedOn"> CreatedOn:</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CreatedOn, new {@class = "form-control", style = "width:185px;background:E1EBF9;", @readonly = "readonly" })
</div>
```

Your `View` should have definition of model:

```
@model EDTSystem.Models.ViewModels.Marie_Testing
```

Please note that `@model` declaration tell the 'View' what is expected from Controller. Inside `Model` which is a `Property` at the end of a day, you have specified instance of `Marie_Testing`, so you should use it as an object.

In your code `MyClass` is not a part of `Marie_Testing`, because it's just separated class (inner class to be precised). If you want to have one place with definition of that `Date`, you should create a `BaseModel` and 'Inherit' from it.

Your controller should obviously return instance of `Marie_Testing` class.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to set property value like this :

```
public class Marie_Testing
{

  ----

  public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

  public Marie_Testing() 
  {
  } 
}
```

or in the class constructor :

```
public class Marie_Testing
{

    ---

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public class Marie_Testing
    {
        CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```